# Wordpress shows ip but all the other pages shows domain

Tags: linux, wordpress, dns

My wordpress home page is like this.

[image: my website ip]

I set my wordpress site address and wp adress are the same (www.sheng****.com)

After I clicked somewhere else on my page, it showed like this.

[image]

and phpmyadmin is like this.

[image]

I am not sure whether it is my DNS problem. I will be appreciate if someone could give me some advice, thank you.
[image]

Comment: Have you checked `siteurl`  and `home` in the database - and checked general settings for your home url?

Comment: @Stender Yes, I have checked that, they are the same domain address of my website.